# multiplicative inverse?

Tags: security, encryption, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

I know that an affine cipher substitutes BD with SG. I need to find the encryption formula, in the form `y = a x + b`, where a and b are coefficients.
From the information above I end up having to equations:
`a+b=18` and
`3a+b=6`
So I am working like this:

```
a+b=18 and 3a + b = 6-> 3a+18-a=6->  2a= 6-18 -> 2a=14 (as it is mod 26)

b=18-a 

2a=?
```

So, O want to multiply by the multiplicative inverse of `2 mod 26`

I can't find a multiplicative inverse of number 2 with 26 (`y = ax + b mod 26`)

Can anyone please help me find a and b?

Comment: Have you heard of http://mathoverflow.net/?

Comment: mathoverflow.net is probably *not* the place to look for answers on this. From their FAQ, ``Though there are no hard and fast rules about who may post here, the intended audience is professional mathematicians, mathematics graduate students, and advanced undergraduates. If your question is closed as "off topic," it might be because it was too elementary.'' Personally, I'm unimpressed by this attitude (since SO seems to do well with both advanced and basic questions), but to each his own.

Comment: I asked a postgraduate student mathematician and she told me that a is impossible to be 7 because there cant be a division because of modulus. It sounds pretty easy but I am struggling for like a week now. And so does a Mathematician. So I am still wondering if a=7 and b=11 is the correct answer.

Comment: Your mathematician must not be well versed in abstract algebra. Keep in mind that mathematics is a very broad topic, someone who studies Analysis might know little about Algebra or Topology.

Comment: Jeremy:  Agreed.  As parochial as StackOverflow is, MathOverflow is even worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because 2 doesn't have a multiplicative inverse mod 26: since 13*2=0, there does not exist K such that K * a = 1. Your modulus must be prime. Try looking up the Chinese Remainder Theorem for more information.

To be more specific, integers mod 26 is not a field (a mathematical set where every element, except 0, has a multiplicative inverse). Any ring in which a * b = 0, for some a!=0 and b!=0, is not a field.

In fact, a field will always have p^n elements, where p is a prime number and n is a positive integer. The simplest fields are just integers mod a prime number, but for prime powers you need to construct a more elaborate system. So, in short, use a different modulus like 29.

Answer (score 2):

Does a = 7 work?  2*7 = 14.  Thus, b = 11.

Let's check the 2 equations to see if that works:

- 7+11 = 18 (check for the first equation).
- 3*7+11=21+11 = 32 = 6.

What is wrong with the above?

EDIT: Ok, now I see what could go wrong with trying to do a division by 2 in a non-prime modulus as it is similar to a division by 0.  You could take ribond's suggestion of using the Chinese Remainder Theorem and split the equations into another pair of pairs:

mod 13: a+b=5, 3a+b=6. (2a = 1 = 14 => a=7.  b = 18-7 = 11.)

mod 2: a+b=0. 3a+b=0 (Note this is the same equation and has a pair of possible solutions where a and b are either 0 or 1.)

Thus there is the unique solution for your problem I think.

Comment: That's what i am thinking of doing. But its just an assumption. I have to find the multiplicative inverse of a number. And as ribond mentioned below there is no multiplicative inverse of 2 with mod 26.
So I am not sure how it works. I am not sure if i have to take a=7 and b=11.

Answer (score 0):

Other posters are right in that there is no inverse of 2 modulo 26, so you can't solve 2a=14 mod 26 by multiplying through by the inverse of 2.  But that doesn't mean that 2a=14 mod 26 isn't solvable.

Consider the general equation cx = d mod n (c=2,d=14,n=26 in your case).  Let g = gcd(c,n).  The equation cx=d has a solution if an only if g divides d.  If g divides d, then there are in fact multiple solutions (g of them).  The equation (c/g)x = d/g mod n/g has a unique solution (call it x_0) because c/g is relatively prime to n/g and therefore has an inverse.  The solutions to the original equation are x_0, x_0 + n/g, ..., x_0 + (g-1)n/g.

In your case c=2,d=14,n=26, and g=2.  g divides d, so first solve the equation (2/2)x = (14/2) mod (26/2) which gives 7.  So both 7 and 7+13=20 solve your original equation.

Note that this means you haven't uniquely determined your affine transformation, two possibilities still exist.  You need another data point...